# API Trello - Keep the connection on the board

Tags: api, trello, windev

is there a way to keep the connection on the trello board until the process is completed? So this way I won't have to give the API key and the token in every URL to make a request or post something and when it finished, it disconnects

I would like something like :

Give the API key and the token at the connection, and make requests without providing them again

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Endpoint works with API token and API Key for authenticate you on services. There's now way to skip it.